# Изображения Google панорам

Tags: google-maps-api

Сами изображения разделены на части, по уровням детализации(zoom) и позицией тайла. Сделал их склеивание, но обнаружил, что в крайних тайлах недоступны изображения. Например, по следующему адресу по идее должна быть часть панорамы, но получаю ответ 400 и черное фото.
http://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client=maps_photos.ugc&panoid=Fa-wHCWazJG6bn7ZjISQCA&output=tile&&x=7&y=0&zoom=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что на таких zoom'ах как 0 или 1, панорама не растянута на всю ширину, и поэтому получается repeat, из-за чего начальная часть панорамы по горизонтали повторяется